# Html, css, and jQuery. Something isnt working in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jQuery and watching a tutorial for a sticky nav bar and something went wrong and idk what to do!

In my Script file I have it so it runs this code on load [http://pastebin.com/XYWR5tKJ][1] and I have a class in css to use with the nav Placeholder wrap.

Well the margin property doesn't seem to be working, if you run the site and scroll the whole way down the nav bar sticks to the side, its supposed to be centered(the margins job). I have no idea why its not doing it, its probably something stupid but please help!`

```
HERES THE CODE__

Script.js: http://pastebin.com/XYWR5tKJ
Css: http://pastebin.com/Y51rYJVE
HTML: http://pastebin.com/tTftEJKh
__

THANKS!


  [1]: http://pastebin.com/tTftEJKh
```

Comment: Code in the link has been removed. Can you please post the correct link.

Comment: And please fix the title to be descriptive. Every question on SO could be summed up with "Something isnt working in my code". And remove the tags from there too.

Comment: What do you mean by "margin property doesn't seem to be working"? Margin on what element?

Comment: Honestly, stack overflow wont let me do it, but whatever.

Comment: Just copy and paste the link

Answer (score 0):

**Basic set up for a fixed, centered element is:**

Containing element that is position fixed.

An element within that has margin:0 auto; and a set width.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that your left:0 inside fixed is counteracting things mostly.

Since you didn't specify responsive is this good enough for you?
http://jsbin.com/nevuqi/4/

Also probably better, as a tip to share code in something like a JSFiddle, Codepen or JSBin to name a few...  good for learning inside of too.

Answer (score 0):

This question reminded me of a [JSFIDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/danoram/m0gba9ka/22/) I made a while back to learn the same concept. I've updated it with comments to make it more readable...

*It doesn't really answer your question but I thought it would help understand the various components involved when implementing the sticky nav effect in JQuery for anyone who comes across this thread who is unsure.*

**JavaScript/JQuery code:**
(refer to jsfiddle for the accompanying html/css )

```
//window - the container that holds and renders the document. 
//document - the rendered html within the window. the document can be bigger than the window as with this example as scrolling is needed..
//refer to css for more info on the appended classes to nav bar and proceeding element.
$(document).ready(function () {
//add a scroll function to the document that 
$(document).on('scroll', function () {

    //get the  number of pixels that the window is from the top of the document. this is zero at first.
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    //insert the name of your sticky nav element here in place of .scrollFixed
    $('.scrollFixed').each(function () {

        //scrollFix variable is initialized as .scrollFixed object with all its attributes.
        var scrollFix = $(this);

        //gets offset of sticky nav element in pixels 
        var topDistance = scrollFix.offset().top;
        var previousElement = scrollFix.prev();

        //this is just for debugging and learning purposes.
        $('.fixed_info').html('nav bar is ' + topDistance + ' pixels from top of document');

        //if you put topDistance here instead of the number manually, the nav bar will flicker.
        //unsure why..
        //checks to see whether nav element has been scrolled past the top of window.
        if ((298) < scrollTop) {

            //make sticky nav a fixed element
            scrollFix.addClass("stuck");

            //extend the element below for this example so proceeding elements don't visually jump up
            //when closing the empty gap.
            $(".element_below_fixed_nav_bar").addClass("extend");

            //indicates element is fixed!
            scrollFix.html("Element now fixed!");

        //you will have to manually put the topDistance here as well...
            //this checks whether the nav element's original top has passed the top of 
            //the enclosing window.
            //it needs to become scrollable again
        } else if (298 >= scrollTop && scrollFix.hasClass('stuck')) {

            //make sticky nav a scrollable element
            scrollFix.removeClass('stuck');

            //make proceeding element shorter to compensate for sticky nav pushing elements below it down.
            $(".element_below_fixed_nav_bar").removeClass("extend");

            //indicates element is scrollable!
            scrollFix.html("Element now moveable!");
        }
    });
});
});
```

It's very similar to the logic behind the JavaScript code you linked.

1. find number of pixels of window from top of document. starts at 0 when document first loads unless otherwise coded.  This updates every time you scroll.
2. find (offset) number of pixels of nav bar element from top of document.
3. check if nav bar has reached the top of the window by checking its offset to the window. If it is then make it fixed.
4. check whether the nav bar's original offset has fallen below the top of the window. If it has then make the nav bar scrollable.

It doesn't really answer your question but I thought it would help understand the various components involved when implementing the sticky nav effect in JQuery for anyone who comes across this thread who is unsure.